# IE: Cannot disable Settings button under Browsing history via group policy

Tags: windows, windows-xp, group-policy, internet-explorer, files

Windows XP Pro SP3, IE8 (8.0.6001.18702), within local gpedit.msc I did the below:

- User Config/Admin Temp/Windows Comp/IE

  - enabled: disable changing temporary internet file settings
- User Config/Admin Temp/Windows Comp/IE/Delete Browsing History

  - enabled all (11 items)

However there is a loophole that lets me still wipe history & other files via: Tools, Internet Options, Browsing History, Settings, View Objects, delete everything, hit up arrow, go to History (hidden folders has to be on), delete everything. Quick solution I could think of, but don't want to do: disable General Internet Options Page

**Ideal solution/answer**: someone to confirm the ability to simply disable that Settings button is/isn't available in group policy & their suggested action

*[This is a re-post from superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/482631/cannot-seem-to-disable-ability-to-view-temporary-internet-files-via-group-policy) where I didn't get the feedback I'd hoped. After reading the rules deeper I find that is not tailored to business environments. [It was offered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7615750#7615750) [that I repost](https://superuser.com/questions/482631/cannot-seem-to-disable-ability-to-view-temporary-internet-files-via-group-policy#comment643285_482631)*

Comment: What is the purpose of that - Browser Kiosk setup? Surveillance?

Comment: Honestly I don't want users covering their tracks. Its actually a laptop in a truck-repair shop that gets used overnight. I speculate things might get boring & things very un-related to work might get looked up. Until I get better Antivirus or a proxy or something I have to rely on hope & accoutability

Comment: Just dont forget that depending on locality there might be legal requirements to inform users (and get them to sign paperwork) about such measures.